# MySQL ADD_DATE for date equal to or after today

Tags: mysql, date

I want to only display a date that I calculate within the query if this date is equal to or after the current date.
In my table I have a 'created' field, which is the date on which a deposit account was opened (TIMESTAMP), and a 'maturity' field, which is a number in months.
I calculate the next maturity like this:

```
DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), INTERVAL maturity MONTH)
```

but when I try to add a comparison:

```
(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), INTERVAL maturity MONTH) >= NOW()) AS next_maturity
```

I only get '01.01.1970'.

Could you help me with this please?

EDIT: It seems I need a more complicated query, perhaps one in which the REPEAT() function is implemented. So, I tried this:

```
SELECT *, 
REPEAT
DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), INTERVAL maturity MONTH) AS next_maturity
UNTIL next_maturity >= NOW())
END REPEAT
AS next_maturity
FROM ?n
```

but the query doesn't work at all, it returns an empty array.

Here's an actual example of what I want to do: `created` is '05.02.2013' and `maturity` is '2'. I will need to add `maturity` to `created` as many times as necessary for `next_maturity` to equal or be after today.

Comment: what type is `created`? is it maybe `null`?

Comment: `created` is INT(11). It is not `NULL`.